# Does this simple Message class justify using a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I am changing my current implementation of a message class from:

```
class Message
{
public:
    Message(uint8* buffer, uint8 length) : m_contents(buffer), m_length(length) { }

    uint8 getLength() const {return m_length; }
    const uint8* getData() const { return m_contents; }
protected:
    uint8* m_contents;
    uint8 m_length;
};
```

To take only length in the constructor, and dynamically allocate in the constructor, and delete in the destructor.

I think it should look like:

```
Message(uint8 length) : m_length(length)
{
    m_contents = new uint8[length];
}

~Message() 
{
    delete [] m_contents;
    m_contents = NULL;
}
```

Additional info: The message object will be passed to a serial port object which will send it off.  It will also be subclassed into multiple CustomMessage classes.

My question is: in this simple example, are there any reasons to use some type of smart pointer?  An example would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Just use a `vector`, and yes: http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero

Comment: Smart pointers or not, you shouldn't be violating the rule of three: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: You've got it backwards: you need justification *not* to use a smart pointer. In this case, actually `std::vector<T>` (or even `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.)

Comment: @NPE isn't it true that when you use smart pointers the rule of 3 becomes the rule of 2; meaning that he still has to implement the assignment operator but not the destructor?

Comment: `typedef std::vector<std::uint8_t> Message;`

Comment: @Nick It depends on the smart pointer.  Unless I'm mistaken, you still have to implement more or less everything with `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, not disagreeing with you, but I wasn't aware that you have to manually delete a `unique_ptr`. Is that so?

Comment: @JamesKanze [No constructors, destructors or operator= required](http://liveworkspace.org/code/33rvSU$7) with a `std::unique_ptr` member.  So long as you are ok with being restricted to move semantics...

Comment: @Nick Perhaps not in this case; I was thinking of the compilation firewall idiom.  `unique_ptr` requires the object to be complete at the point of deletion, which in the case of the compilation firewall idiom, means that you cannot use the default destructor (which is inline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are there any reasons to use some type of smart pointer?

Actually it depends. Consider this code:

```
 Message m1 (1024);
 Message m2 (m1);
```

Do you want `m2`  to be a deep-copy of `m1`? Do you want the underlying buffer of `m1` and `m2` to share memory? Or you don't want the copy to begin with (deep or otherwise)? That is, the second statement should result in compilation error?

- If you want them to share memory, then yes, you should use `std::shared_ptr`.
- If you want them to be completely different copy in memory (deep-copy), then no, you should not use `shared_ptr`; you can use `std::unique_ptr` though, but you have to implement copy-semantic also. But then if you go with this case, then it is better to use `std::vector<uint8>` instead of implementing your own class:

  ```
  typedef std::vector<uint8> Message;

  Message m1(1024);
  Message m2(m1); //m2 is a deep-copy of m1
  ```
- If you want to prevent copy and thus the second statement should result in compilation error, then you've to disable copy-semantic by `=deleteing` them as:

  ```
  Message(Message const &) = delete;
  Message& operator=(Message const &) = delete;
  ```

  Note that in this case you've to implement the move-semantic yourself. Move usually makes sense, so I wouldn't comment on that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 Great Answer. I especially love the lack of dogmatism, unlike some who'd exclaim **YOU MUST USE SMART POINTERS ALWAYS**

Comment: Interesting, I am completely fine with a copy that has no shared memory resulting in two completely separate objects.  Vector is looking pretty good.

Comment: Good answer, but you forgot the option no copy.

Comment: Most of the time, if you don't support copy, you don't want move either.  (But for this class, value semantics---either deep copy or shallow copy---seem more approriate, which means either `std::shared_ptr` or `std::vecdtor`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze really?  `move` is often much easier than a deep copy, and makes things like factory functions have much better syntax.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Standard stream classes are movable but not copyable, so is `std::unique_ptr`. I see *more* examples where move makes sense even though copy doesn't.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I can't agree with that at all. There is really no reason not to want move, just because copy is problematic. In many cases move is much easier to implement then copy (since one doesn't need to duplicate resources for that one) and having `move` will let you pass and return the object by value enabling much nicer interfaces.

Comment: @Yakk For returning an object from a factory function, move is ideal.  For a class with value semantics, however, move semantics just don't cut it.

Comment: @Nawaz The standard stream classes have move semantics for a very specific reason: they have identity (and the identity moves with the class).  The most important aspect is that they _don't_ support copy.  Even in pre-C++11, when there wasn't any move.  And `unique_ptr` is just a tool, to use when appropriate, and _not_ something you use for itself.

Comment: @Grizzly There are cases where move is appropriate; if you end up passing instances of this class around a lot, you might want it for performance reasons.  But the semantics of this class seem to require support for copy.  _If_ copying turns out to be a bottle neck, you can add move later.

Comment: @JamesKanze this class will be passed around, but I am much more concerned with safety rather than performance.  So I should use a vector implementation.  And when passing the message to a different object, I am fine with passing a copy of the object, this seems to me to be the safer choice.

Comment: So @Grizzly, why is move much easier to implement than copy?  seems to me to be the opposite.

Comment: @JamesKanze they may not be enough, but your claim was "if you don't want copy, you don't want move".  And I don't see where you are actually supporting that claim.  `move` is often easy to write, and adds utility.  Shallow copy is often dangerous, and deep copy often requires non-trivial effort, and `move` is easy and safe.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I would rather like to hear the issues with movable-only class. Can you tell me any issue with movable-only class?

Comment: @Raskol `swap` is easy to write, right?  `move` via `swap` is rather quick to write, and writing pure-move is about as hard as writing `swap`.

Comment: @Yakk Could you point me to a resource to learn the details of move via swap vs pure move, etc?

Comment: Swap `*this` with other for move.  For move construct first default construct.  Easy.  Not perfect. @Raskol

Comment: @Yakk My experience with move is that it is full of subtle issues, and remarkably difficult to get right.  I'd avoid it unless performance requires it.

Comment: @Nawaz The biggest problems with move involve inheritance.  Handling move correctly in an inheritance hierarchy is non-trivial.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I understand that but here I don't see any inheritance. So why is `move` bad *here*?

Comment: @jameskanze ctor: trivial construct.  `swap` self with other.  `=`: swap self with other, return `*this`.  Classes without pointers to internal structure are done, assuming valid dtor and ctor and `swap`.  And have you found `swap` hard to write?  This is the equivalent of the copy swap idiom (the easy way to write copy `=`), but without having to write a copy ctor.  It does require a cheaply constructed trivial instance.  But there really is not anything difficult to get right.

Comment: @Nawaz Because the class seems to have value semantics, and requires full copy.  Adding `move` is just extra complexity, unless it is really needed for performance reasons.  KISS rules.

Comment: @Yakk I've recently done a hierarchy with `move`, and it's been a nightmare, with all sorts of additional forwarding constructors needed.  (If I had to do it again, I'd have just used `shared_ptr`.  And everything would have worked as expected.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Could you please point out what is extra complexity in *this* case? I think it is pretty much straight-forward. It will increase performance for sure!

Comment: @Nawaz You need to declare an implement the extra functions.  And I doubt that it will have any effect on performance, because in practice, I suspect that the objects are rarely if ever copied, except maybe in cases where RVO would suppress the copy anyway.

Comment: @JamesKanze: *"because in practice, I suspect that the objects are rarely if ever copied"*.  What if they're copied in some cases, and the programmer couldn't notice it. Also, whether RVO works or not depends on the compiler, and the programmers code. So given these complexities, isn't it relatively *easier* to write the move-semantics than finding out the unnecessary copies (and the bottle-neck due to them, **and** then implementing the move-semantics to gain performance)?

Comment: @Nawaz Who cares?  Unless it makes a measurable difference in performance, there's no reason to bother with the extra complexity.  If profiling later shows that you have a performance problem, there's no problem adding move semantics then, but doing so earlier is a flagrent case of premature optimization.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't think it falls into the "*premature optimization*" category, especially when it is very easy to implement for *this* case, and the advantage it can give is enormous!

Comment: @jameskanze You finding something hard is not strong evidence it is hard in general: `swap` is rarely hard.  And in this case `= default` is not hard, as all three examples work just fine with default move.

Comment: @Nawaz It clearly falls into the premature optimization category, because it adds significant complexity, making it harder to derive from the class, and probably doesn't make any difference in the execution time of the application.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That is another argument you came up with. It makes harder for the derived class, not for itself. Also, I don't see any derivation here.

Comment: @Nawaz The only argument is that it is useless excess complexity, unless you really need it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: How about copy-semantic? Why not you argument against it too? I don't believe move-semantic *""is full of subtle issues, and remarkably difficult to get right"* unless you show me, or refer me to some article that supports your claim.

Answer (score 1):

What is the policy with regards to copy and assignment.  If you
make the classes uncopyable, there's no real advantage in using
a smart pointer.  If you support deep copy, I don't think that
there's a standard smart pointer which will do the job; you'll
have to implement copy and assignment yourself.  Or use
`std::vector<char>`, which will do all that for you.  If you support
shallow copy, then `std::shared_ptr` is perfect for the job.

If the class is immuatable after construction (which it is if
you've shown all of the members), shallow copy or no copy is the
way to go.  To be frank, I'd probably just use `std::string` or
`std::vector` here and not worry about it.  It gives deep copy
by default, which may be overkill, but it's certainly the
simplest solution.